# Infinite Error when use async pipe and #select decorator in redux angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, angular9

I code simple example for using redux in angular 9 .
the code is working good when i write .

```
 count: number=0;
 constructor(
   private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, 
   private actions: CounterActions  ) 
      {
         var subscription=ngRedux.subscribe(()=>{
         var store =ngRedux.getState();
         this.count =store.count
      });
     }
```

and in html

```
  Count: {{ count}}
```

But when the error occures in the next section .
at ts.

```
@select() count ;
```

and at html

```
      Count: {{ count |async}}
```

it release infinit error

[image: infinite error]

Comment: Are you still assigning `this.count = store.count` when the definition is `@select() count;`? If so, please remove it try again.

Comment: no i didn't use this.count=store.count when the definition is @select() count;

Answer (score -1):

in your code count is not an observable. that's why you are getting this error. check type of count after you get it.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: can you try changing count: number = 0  to count = of(0)

Comment: do you mean    @select() count = of(0)  ;

Comment: the problem occures when i use @select  ==> at the second part of code